# CouchDb view - key in a list

Tags: couchdb

I Want to query CouchDB and I have a specific need : my query should return the name field of documents corresponding to this condition : the id is equal or contained in a document filed (a list).
For example, the field output is the following :

```
"output": [
       "doc_s100",
       "doc_s101",
       "doc_s102",
       "doc_s103",
   ],
```

I want to get all the documents having in their output field "doc_s102" for example.
I wrote a view in a design document :

```
"backward_by_docid": {
           "map": "function(doc) {if(doc.output) emit(doc.output, doc.name)}"
       }
```

but this view works only when I have a unique value in the output field.
How can I resolve this query ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 4):

you have to iterate over the array:

```
  if(doc.output) {
      for (var curOutput in doc.output) {
        emit (doc.output[curOutput],doc.name);
      }
  }
```

make sure that output always is an array (at least [])

.. and, of course use key="xx" instead key=["xxx"]